# How do I restore the Gnome Panel volume control in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, gnome

I use alsa, and I don't have a volume control applet on my Gnome Panel.

When I right click and select "add to panel", there is nothing that has to do with "sound", "audio" or "volume" in the list, and the "Indicator Applet" or "Indicator Applet Session" things have no volume controls, or properties that would let you enable any sort of volume control.

How can I get a volume control in Ubuntu, so I don't have to run aumix in a terminal or something?

**So I've got the thing working now. But does anyone know why the new, fancy "Indicator Applet" volume control doesn't appear? The Gnome Volume Control Applet isn't as nicely featured, although it actually works.**

*I've been using Linux since Redhat 5, it's beyond me why these sorts of problems are still around. Someone should just put a damn "Volume Control" element in the list of things to add to the panel, even if it doesn't work, perhaps showing an error message.*

Comment: One of the changes in 10.04 is a rearrangement of the way the panel works. See [page 2 of this review](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/reviews/2010/05/lucid-dream-ars-reviews-ubuntu-1004.ars/2).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Click on *System > Preferences > Startup Applications*.  When that loads, click on Add, then add the following:

- Name: Volume control
- Command: `gnome-sound-applet`
- Comment: Launch volume control applet

That will launch the applet every time you start up and give you the icon in the notification area.

Comment: This is the most complete answer. I actually found this in a forum as well.

Comment: Just upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04, the executable is now called `gnome-sound-applet`.

Answer (score 4):

The volume control is no longer a panel applet. It now sits in the system tray. Run `gnome-volume-control-applet` to start it.

Comment: This works, but only when you use pulseaudio, which makes my speakers pop, but I can live with that for now. Maybe some day pulseaudio won't be crap.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

Source: http://www.virtualhelp.me/linux/107-volume-controlicon-is-gone-ubuntu-1004

1. Right-click on the panel where you'd
   like the volume controller to appear
   and select "Add to panel"
2. Choose "Indicator Applet" from the list and
   click on "Add" and you're done.

The volume control should be back.

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on the `Panel >> Click Add to Panel >> Search Indicator Applet >> Click Add` then `Close` the window.

Now you will get the volume indicator on the panel.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in terminal:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.sound visible true
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the panel, from the contextual menu, click on "Reset panel", on the dialog box that comes up, confirm by clicking on "Reset panel". The defaults, including the volume, is restored.

Answer (score -2):

Just add the indicator applet and this should solve the problem.

You are right that the Gnome Volume Control is nothing like the one you have with the indicator applet.

Comment: This just shows you an email icon, and some other irrelevant things. It's useless in the context of volume control.